# sending request payload with oatpp

Tags: c++, oat++

I am a beginner to oatpp and building a crud operation demo application. I want to send only two of these four properties (id, name, email, salary) in dto for change email service, in the request payload like below:

```
{
 "id":"1",
 "email":"email1"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by either creating a separate DTO containing these two fields and then assign values,
or by returning `oatpp::Fields<oatpp::Any>`.

## Using oatpp::Any

```cpp
  ENDPOINT("GET", "/", myEndpoint) {
    oatpp::Fields<oatpp::Any> responseDto = {
      {"id", oatpp::Int32(1)},             //<-- put your id here
      {"email", oatpp::String("email1")}   //<-- put your email here
    };
    return createDtoResponse(Status::CODE_200, responseDto);
  }
```

result:

```
{"id":1,"email":"email1"}
```

Comment: @Iganzzzo, I can't create new DTO since my requirement to do with that DTO, I have done that but that rejected. So I have only one option.

Comment: @Iganzzzo, and want to return all data of that DTO related to that id which updated email.